# cPanel web mail does not receive or send mails

Tags: cpanel, webmail

In my cPanel account few e-mail accounts are working properly, but some of the email account does not receive or send mails.

here are the errors that I got:
when sending from a gmail account to the cPanel mail:

SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550 High probability of spam

When trying to send from the cPanel email account to my gmail account I get the following message:
Could not deliver message, address not found or don't receive messages.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I would appreciate if who ever down vote my question will add a comment why so I will know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons why this error could occur.

Before that I would recommend that you turn on your Email accounts' Authentication (both SPF and DKIM), those are done through:

```
cPanel -> Authentication (under the Email section) -> Turn Off DKIM and SPF, then turn them back On
```

About the second issue - I believe that your domain's mail exchanger (a setting in cPanel) is not properly configured.

If you wish to receive emails for a domain in your cPanel account you need to the following:

```
cPanel -> Mail Exchanger -> Select your domain -> Select Local Mail Exchanger
```

You should also see if your mailbox is not Suspended or Partially Suspended

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt that cPanel is one of the renowned and most prominent control panels for effortlessly using the functionalities of a website. However, if you're facing the issue of cPanel email not working then, you're not alone in the queue. It is considered as the most typical issue users experience while managing their webmail. Since you have already mentioned that you're unable to send the emails. Here are some of the professional suggested methods you can utilize to quickly resume your services. Let's begin to know the solution.

1. Unblock the IP Address:- There are multiple instances when the blockage of IP prevents users from sending or receiving emails. For the same, it is important to understand the inevitable role of IP addresses. Hence, you should make a list of blocked IDs and then, identify the specific blocked one from the server. With this, you need to unblock the IP address to resume the services of cPanel webmail not working.
2. Clear Your Browser Caches:- Besides the above-mentioned solution, you should clear the history or cookies of your web browser using the designed settings. Moreover, the significance of using this method helps to clean the cache history as it can gradually harm the performance and result in cPanel email not sending.

Besides this, professionals suggest users take the [backup cPanel webmail](https://macwaretools.com/blog/backup-cpanel-mail-email/) as it is convenient for the individual to access the data even in the remote or unresponsiveness condition of cPanel.

3. Firewall Issue:- Sometimes the advanced functionalities of a firewall can curb the passage of sending or receiving emails. Moreover, the robust and well-designed structure of firewall security can help to mitigate malware and virus attacks. In a similar way, there are possibilities that it has blocked the IP due to which you can’t send the emails. For the same, you need to manually fix the issue of cPanel email not sending along with unblocking the IPs.

Lastly, using any of these practices, you can easily fix the problem of your cPanel webmail. However, if you’re frequently facing this issue then, downloading the emails is among the best ways to deal with or access the crucial data of your webmail on your system.